# Why I can't get access to my column?

Tags: c#, telerik-grid

I'm using `Telerik` grid view and I can't get access to my column in this code:

```
foreach (var Row in radGridView1.Rows)
{
    _MyAmount.Add((int)Row["Amount"].Text);
}
```

The code above first converts and after that fills a list.

I keep receiving this error:

> 'Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewRowInfo.this[Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewColumn]'
>   is inaccessible due to its protection level

And in this part `Row["Amount"].` in the bracket I should type column name, am I right?

What should I do to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach (GridDataItem Row in radGridView1.Items)
{
  _MyAmount.Add((int)Row["Amount"].Text);
}
```

Comment: radGridView1.Items it dosent know item [it gives me an error]

Comment: wen you press ( . ) you cant find ( item )

Comment: this line? `foreach (GridDataItem Row in radGridView1.Items)`

Comment: Try using `EditItems` instead of `Items`

Comment: If above comment does not work then try `radGridView1.MasterView.Rows`